# Register an application to a URL protocol (all browsers) via installer

Tags: windows, installation

I know this is possible via a simple registry change  to accomplish this as long as IE/firefox is being used.  However, I am wondering if there is a reliable way to do so for other browsers,

I am specifically looking for a way to do this via an installer, so editing a preference inside a specific browser will not cut it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the best I can come up with:

**IE**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx

**FireFox**: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol

**Chrome**: Since every other browser in seems to support the same convention, I created a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5502) for chrome.

**Opera**: I can't find any documentation, but it appears to follow the same method as IE/Firefox (see above links)

**Safari**: Same thing as opera, it works, but I can't find any documentation on it

Comment: Does not work in Safari at all for me, seeAlso http://caniuse.com/#feat=registerprotocolhandler

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Here is how to do it with FireFox:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol

and Opera:

http://www.opera.com/support/kb/view/535/

Comment: the link for opera requires the user to configure the browser, I'm looking for something i can configure during installation.  I just edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

If someone looks like a solution for an intranet web site (for all browsers, not only IE), that contains hyperlinks to a shared server folders (like in my case) this is a possible solution:

1. [register protocol (URI scheme)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767914(v=vs.85)) via registry (this can be done for all corporative users i suppose). For example, "myfile:" scheme. (thanks to Greg Dean's answer)
2. The hyperlink href attribute will then should look like

   ```
   <a href='myfile:\\mysharedserver\sharedfolder\' target='_self'>Shared server</a>
   ```
3. Write a console application that redirects argument to windows explorer (see step 1 for example of such application)

This is piece of mine test app:

```
const string prefix = "myfile:";

static string ProcessInput(string s)
{
    // TODO Verify and validate the input 
    // string as appropriate for your application.
    if (s.StartsWith(prefix))
        s = s.Substring(prefix.Length);

    s = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(s);

    Process.Start("explorer", s);

    return s;
}
```

I think this app can be easily installed by your admins for all intranet users :)

*I couldn't set up scheme setting to open such links in explorer without this separate app.*